# Only a type can be imported. MyClass resolves to a package

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, osgi, aem

I have a maven project with multiple modules. The root pom.xml has these modules.

```
<modules>
    <module>core</module>
    <module>ui.apps</module>
    <module>ui.content</module>
</modules>
```

Each one of these modules has their own pom.xml

I have `MyClass.java` Under core at `core/src/main/java/org/demo/mine/MyClass.java`

When I try to import it in `Mycomponent.java` under `ui.apps` at `ui.apps/src/main/content/jcr_root/apps/mine/components/content/mycomponent/Mycomponent.java` I get the following error

> Only a type can be imported. org.demo.mine.MyClass resolves to a
>   package

I clean build and install using `mvn clean install -PautoInstallPackage`

Comment: Who or what is giving you this error message?

Comment: AEM gives me that error message when I try to add a component to the page. But I believe its a problem with some maven settings...

Comment: Show us `Mycomponent.java`. Show us the actual component's markup.

Comment: Check the bundle that contains the class. Is it active? Is the class exported from the bundle?

Answer (score 0):

```
Only a type can be imported. org.demo.mine.MyClass resolves to a package
```

means that the `org.demo.mine.MyClass` can not be found. Probably you didn't exported `org.demo.mine` from your core module. To investigate what is the problem:

1. check in [OSGi console](http://localhost:4502/system/console/bundles) if your core module bundle is correctly
2. chceck your core module exported packages in [OSGi console](http://localhost:4502/system/console/bundles)
3. check `Export-Package:` entry in the core module manifest.mf file
4. check version of your core module bundle installed (rise the project version and install again)